# Mesos scheduler getting duplicate status updates

Tags: apache, scheduler, mesos

My scheduler gets duplicate terminal status updates from executors. I have noticed that this mainly happens when the scheduler is getting a lot of status updates from many executors. I tried searching what might be causing it but couldn't find anything. Is mesos master supposed to send an ack to the slave?

More concretely, my statusUpdate method in the scheduler gets called multiple times for the exact same status update from an executor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mesos promises to send status updates to the framework scheduler at-least-once, in order. That means that the slave has a queue of pending status updates, and will continue sending the last unacknowledged status update until it receives an acknowledgement from the framework scheduler. This should be done automatically by the SchedulerDriver, but if you have a lot of updates from a lot of executors, it's possible that the slave has resent the status update before the SchedulerDriver had a chance to send that particular ACK.

Your scheduler should be prepared to handle duplicate status updates anyway, since there's always a chance that the ACK did not make it to the slave. This could happen if the master failed over before it was able to forward the ACK, or if the ACK message was just dropped on the floor somehow.